# Keeping a value during a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

In Haskell, I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to have a function that receives a list of integers and returns the biggest product of two adjacent numbers.

Example: f [5,6,1,3,9] would return 30, that is the product of 5 and 6

The function type would be something like this:

```
f :: [Int] -> Int
```

I thought to solve that using recursion to iterate the list getting the 2 head elements with a pattern like this: `(x1:x2:xs)`
The problem is that I don't know how to keep the product value to compare if the current product is bigger than the last product.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if one gives the empty list? Or a list with one element?

Comment: Can you think of a way to create a list with every pair of adjacent numbers, `f [5, 6, 1, 3, 9] == [(5, 6), (6, 1), (1, 3), (3, 9)]`?

Comment: Another possibility would be to make a recursive helper function `go`, that has an additional argument used as intermediate result (your current maximum). The problem: you have to find an initial value. Therefore consider changing the return type of your function and of the intermediate result to an `Maybe Int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Haskell lists are lazy, you can solve this problem using a list-based approach instead of explicitly holding onto a maximum without losing efficiency. Starting with the original list:

```
> let f x = x
> f [5,6,1,3,9]
[5,6,1,3,9]
```

get a list of pairs by [`zip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip)ping the entire list with a left-shifted list:

```
> let f x = zip x (tail x)
> f [5,6,1,3,9]
[(5,6),(6,1),(1,3),(3,9)]
```

use the related function [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to get products instead of pairs:

```
> let f x = zipWith (*) x (tail x)
> f [5,6,1,3,9]
[30,6,3,27]
```

and get the [maximum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) from that list:

```
> let f x = maximum (zipWith (*) x (tail x))
> f [5,6,1,3,9]
30
```